# MongoDb corrupt collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded Mongo 2.4.3 setup

When I want to try to run a query on one of my collections, i get the error `exception: BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO`

I've already ran a `db.repairDatabase`, but that didn't seem to have helped much.

When I just do `db.collection.findOne()`, it runs fine, but when i do e.g. `db.collection.find({'_id': {'$gte': ObjectId("52631d000000000000000000")}}`, i get the error above.

I've read that this might is because of a corrupt index, so I tried:

```
db.collection.reIndex();
{
    "raw" : {
        "rs0/ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017" : {
            "nIndexesWas" : 2,
            "errmsg" : "exception: BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO",
            "code" : 10334,
            "ok" : 0
        }
    },
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "{ rs0/ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017,ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017: \"exception: BSONObj size: 0 (0x00000000) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: EOO\" }"
}
```

I've also dropped all indexes before doing this, only the one on _id is left

```
db.collection.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "db.collection",
        "name" : "_id_"
    }
]
```

Still no luck and I'm running out of ideas here. Anyone has another suggestion? The collection has about 900M documents, so I realy need to recover this

Comment: Have you tried dropping the index rather than reindexing straight off?

Comment: The only index left is the one on _id, which can't be dropped, all other indexes have been dropped

Comment: I don't think index repair will work, ever. The BSON object is corrupt which is your main collection. I had the same issue once but it worked fine. Let me review the internal doc info to see if I can help.

Answer (score 6):

If you have run repair successfully already, then you have already rewritten all of your data from scratch and then rebuilt the indexes, so you have a brand new `_id` index already - you've effectively dropped and rebuilt that index already.

You have a replica set (rs0), so what happens if you step down the current primary? - is the corruption on the other nodes also, or just one?

If just one, (or at the very least you have one node that does not have the issue) then wipe the instances with corruption and have them [resync](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/), it will pull the data from one of the remaining "good" nodes and get rid of the corruption.  This would be the preferred method (by far) to get rid of this corruption, it's one of the intended uses of replica sets in the first place.

If that is not an option, and all of the nodes show the same problem (this would be odd), then you should attempt to do the following:

1. Run the entire instance (i.e. shut down the mongod process, and then restart) with [--repair](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#repair), and have it rebuild all data (local, all databases, all indexes) from scratch.
2. *If, and only if* that does not remove the corruption, then the approach of last resort is to try [mongodump --repair](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--repair) - this method will try all reasonable ways to resolve the issue, and may produce duplicate documents (depending on the level of corruption).  Hence you may need more disk space than was originally used by `mongod` for storage for this to complete.

Finally, you should upgrade to a later version of MongoDB, particularly in a sharded environment.  As of writing this answer, the current version is 2.4.9 and it has several important bug fixes - full details can be found in the release announcements over on [mongodb-announce](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-announce).

Comment: When I run it on the PRIMARY, i get :

rs0:PRIMARY> db.collection.find({'_id':{'$gte':ObjectId('52631d000000000000000000')}}).limit(1);
error: {
 "$err" : "getFile(): bad file number value (corrupt db?): run repair",
 "code" : 10295
}

Comment: this means you have a secondary? why not just use the data from the secondary?  stepDown the primary, let the secondary become primary then resync the old primary.

Comment: **important fact** :    _`mongodump  --repair` is only available for use with mongod instances using the mmapv1 storage engine. You cannot run --repair with mongos or with mongod instances that use the wiredTiger storage  engine.  To  repair data in a mongod instance using wiredTiger use `mongod --repair`_

Comment: it's a decent thing to note, but the reason why this information is omitted is that when written WT didn't exist as an option, and the question specifies this related to version 2.4.3